# Download PDF in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on an api which returns a PDF link. I can put that link into a button, and when users click on that link, it'll download a PDF to their computer. I wonder if there is a way, so that when users click on the link the first time, it'll download the file. But if they click on the link the second time, it just opens a modal with the PDF content inside of it? That way they don't have to download the file again and again.
It's confidential so I can't tell how the link look like, but it's a PDF link stored in s3 aws.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you need to store the information that if the user clicked the button before or not. The options for storing that information is:

1. Local Storage
2. Cookie
3. Your backend

I would suggest not to involve your backend on this, you can just write to localStorage when user clicks that link for the first time and set something like pdfDownloadedPreviously. If you have multiple pdfs like this, you would need to define a unique key for each of them so they don't override each other.

And in your program logic, you can read this from the localStorage, if that key exists in the localStorage then you open your modal, otherwise download.